# Common "include" file between shell and makefile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I've created an (makefiles oriented) include file which contains some variables defined to be used on by others makefiles.

```
# this is myinclude/makevars file
MY_FOLDER:=$(ROOT_FOLDER)/my/folder
ANOTHER_FOLDER:=$(MY_FOLDER)/another/folder
MY_LIB:=$(ANOTHER_FOLDER)/lib
```

this "include file" works just great if I include it in other makefiles:

```
include myinclude/makevars
```

but would be cool if I might include it in some shell script too!.
Currently I've created another file (myinclude/shellvars) very similar but "shell" oriented:

```
# this is myinclude/shellvars file
MY_FOLDER=$ROOT_FOLDER/my/folder
ANOTHER_FOLDER=$MY_FOLDER/another/folder
MY_LIB=$ANOTHER_FOLDER/lib
```

clearly by including this in my (shell) scripts anything works but I have a duplicated file with (semantically) the same info!

any idea to have this two files "merged" into one (myinclude/makevars and myinclude/shellvars) ? any special syntax?
any help is clearly appreciated!

-- kasper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
eval "$(cat makevars.inc | tr -d '(:)')"
echo "$MY_LIB"
```

This loads the text of the target include file into memory, erases all colons and parentheses from it and then executes the result.